# Can't make csshX working on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos

`csshX` not working on Mac Big Sur.

> Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185. Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have FIXED IT!

The whole thing was that Apple used in MacOS Catalina perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) as a default, but in Big Sur perl 5, version 28, subversion 2 (v5.28.2)

csshX is not compatible with 5.28 so the easiest way is to change the default one by this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version -string 5.18
```

since Apple kept the previous version:

```
sh-3.2# ls -l /usr/bin/perl* 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 140176 Jan 1 2020 /usr/bin/perl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 139184 Jan 1 2020 /usr/bin/perl5.18 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 121472 Jan 1 2020 /usr/bin/perl5.28 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 121472 Jan 1 2020 /usr/bin/perl5.30
```

and Voilà - csshX is working again!

Comment: Thank you, the solution was so easy, but ...

Comment: Thank you, this worked straight forward, awesome. It also worked for macOS Monterey

Comment: Users may want to be wary of pinning the system default to a specific version, which will get more and more outdated over time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70283732/10802328 is way less intrusive and gets my vote

Answer (score 25):

change line create tmp file in CsshX.iterm

```
use POSIX   qw(tmpnam);
```

by

```
use File::Temp  qw(tmpnam);
```

Comment: Silly question, but where is the file CsshX.iterm?

Comment: Not a silly question. I had the same one :)

So I found the file where the `use POSIX     qw(tmpnam);` lines are there on my big sur setup, it is `/usr/local/Cellar/csshx/0.74/bin/csshX`. But when I've replaced the occurrences in it as instructed, I get a new error: | "uname" is not exported by the File::Temp module
| Can't continue after import errors at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 25.0
| BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 25.
| (have denoted line breaks with | here for readability)

Comment: That error was because I edited an extra line. Not all `use POSIX` lines need editing. Only the one which uses `tmpnam` method.

The fix works great, thanks!

Comment: @Sankalp : are you sur from the version files you have. I have the same configuration  files csshX & csshX.iterm in the bigsur Mac Os from the github repository
https://github.com/brockgr/csshx

Comment: @Shb.A are you facing the same problem?

Comment: @Sankalp: I had the same problem with `use POSIX qw(tmpnam);` and I changed by `use File::Temp  qw(tmpnam);` only in big sur

Comment: One liner for those who have to do it frequently:


`sed -i.bak 's/POSIX \(.*tmpnam.*\)/File::Temp \1/' /usr/local/Cellar/csshx/0.74/bin/csshX`

Comment: I tired this but now I am getting the error `"uname" is not exported by the File::Temp module`

Comment: @tuk : you can download from this GitHub https://github.com/souhaib22/csshx

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but now I am faced with another error - 

"Undefined subroutine &CsshX::Config::uname called at /usr/local/bin/csshx line 80."

Any Suggestions how to resolve this issue? @tuk Did you found any solutions, since you faced the same issue?

Comment: Hello @Rishikesh : which version of Perl do you have? And the version of macOS?

Comment: I am using the version from github.com/souhaib22/csshx with macOS Ventura without modifying the default version as indicated here defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version -string 5.18, my version of perl : `This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 3 (v5.30.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Answer (score 17):

Replace first line of the csshX with perl5.18 version.

Edit csshX file and replace the first line `#!/usr/bin/perl` with `#!/usr/bin/perl5.18`

Comment: This solution is much 'cleaner' (because more 'local') than the proposed defaulting of perl5.18 in the accepted answer. Works like a charm on osx 12.4 (monterey)

Comment: can you also tell where this file is usually placed?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/csshx/0.74/bin/csshX

Comment: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/csshx/0.74/bin/csshX for Apple Silicon (M1 and newer)

Answer (score 7):

On Ventura exec:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version -string 5.30
```

Make the file `/usr/local/bin/csshx` writable with:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/csshX
```

Then edit it with vim or nano to change line 1130 from POSIX to File::Temp

```
use File::Temp   qw(tmpnam);
```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me initially. So, I changed the file permission for the file as mention in one of the solution. Then this change reflected. It's working with perl 5.30 itself. We can also edit the file as sudo instead of changing file permission, this is also mentioned in that same solution. Thanks!

Comment: It works, had to change permission, edited the answer to show permission instructions

Comment: I think using the `defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version -string 5.30` command tells the system to use version 5.30 of perl everywhere. This might have unintended consequences. It's safer to [edit the csshX file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75815023/3461729) to use an older version of perl

Answer (score 4):

Since I switched to mac (with Apple M1 Pro chip), I had this problem. I resolved it after considering all answers and making it less intrusive.

check perl versions

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/perl* 
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  169856 Feb  9 01:39 /usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  134608 Feb  9 01:39 /usr/bin/perl5.30
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  134608 Feb  9 01:39 /usr/bin/perl5.34
-rwxr-xr-x  28 root  wheel     811 Feb  9 01:39 /usr/bin/perlbug
```

add the write permision only to yourself

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/csshx
```

edit first line of csshx from #!/usr/bin/perl with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.30
```

change line 1130 from POSIX to File::Temp

```
use File::Temp   qw(tmpnam);
```

Comment: No need to edit the file permissions when you can use sudo and vi. `sudo vi /usr/local/bin/csshx` and then `w!` to overwrite the protected file.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine by

- add the write permision for all user on the file /usr/local/bin/csshX

  ```
   chmod ugo+w /usr/local/bin/csshX
  ```
- edit the file /usr/local/bin/csshX by updating the first line from #!/usr/bin/perl with #!/usr/bin/perl5.18

Comment: Changing permissions is unnecessary, just use sudo, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70283732/10802328 is a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing using the homebrew, then edit the file at this location: `/usr/local/bin/csshX`,

Command:

```bash
sudo vi /usr/local/bin/csshX
```

and on line one replace `#!/usr/bin/perl` with `#!/usr/bin/perl5.18`.