# Csshx not working after updating mac os to Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: macos-ventura

My current MacOS version is Ventura - 13.2.1 (22D68)
I was facing the below issue,
`Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185. Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.`

So I did the changes in the csshX file as mentioned
so my current code looks like this,

`use base    qw(CsshX::Socket::Selectable); #use POSIX   qw(tmpnam); use File::Temp qw/ :POSIX /; use FindBin qw($Bin $Script);;`

However I am getting this below error now,
`Can't locate Foundation.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Foundation module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.34 /Network/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.34 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.34.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.34 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.34) at (eval 8) line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 8) line 1.`

I see this in csshX
`my $terminal; sub init { eval "use Foundation; use List::Util qw(min max) "; die $@ if $@;`

Can anyone help me how can I install this Foundation module into perl?

To install the Foundation module I searched for this on CPAN and I am seeing multiple results. Not really sure which one to install

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't make csshX working on Mac OS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64837097/cant-make-csshx-working-on-mac-os-big-sur)

Answer (score -1):

ajunB7 commented on Aug 5, 2020
I fixed it via the following:

in /usr/local/bin/csshX

change use POSIX   qw(tmpnam); to use File::Temp qw/ :POSIX /;

https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/issues/103

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).