# Not able to use csshX in MacOS Ventura

Tags: macos, macos-ventura

I installed csshX on my mac Ventura (13.5.2) and when I tried using it, I got the following error -

```
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185. 
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130. 
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.
```

I resolved this issue using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64884636/9596831).

However, now I am getting this issue -

`Undefined subroutine &CsshX::Config::uname called at /usr/local/bin/csshx line 80.`

Anybody have any solutions for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall csshx -> `brew uninstall csshx`, then, and re-install csshx with these two steps.

**Step 1**: Add the tap:

```
brew tap parera10/csshx
```

**Step 2**: Then install csshx again:

```
brew install parera10/csshx/csshx
```

Finally, `csshx` will work just fine.

For example: `csshx host1 host2 host3 host4`